# Check that python function is defined for a particular input?

Tags: python, function

I have tried the following which doesn't work:

```
  try:
     f = h5py.File(filepath)
  except NameError:
     f = scipy.io.loadmat(filepath)
```

Basically, a user will pass a particular input(a filepath) to a function which is 
supposed to load the data in that file. But, I don't expect the user to know whether the function is defined for that input.

I'm getting the following error:

```
OSError: Unable to create file (Unable to open file: name = '/users/cyrilrocke/documents/c_elegans/data/chemotaxis/n2laura_benzaldehyde_l_2013_03_17__15_39_19___2____features.mat', errno = 17, error message = 'file exists', flags = 15, o_flags = a02)
```

Note: basically, I want to be able to switch between the function `h5py.File()` and `scipy.io.loadmat()` depending on which one doesn't work. Given the inputs, one of these functions must work.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: just added this to question details...

Comment: If you're asking "how do I tell ahead of time if calling a function will make it raise an exception?", you can't. You would have to solve the Halting Problem to do that. If you're asking "why does this crash even though I have a try-except?" it's because you're catching NameError, not OSError. (assuming h5py.File is the line causing the exception, which isn't clear because you didn't provide the whole stack trace)

Comment: can you provide sample input and expected output for that input?

Comment: Is the error generated in the second or fourth line?

Comment: @Rogalski If the function is defined for h5py.File(filepath), then I can check that type(f) == h5py._hl.files.File

Comment: @SimoV8 The error is generated by the second line. Basically, I want to be able to switch between the function h5py.File() and scipy.io.loadmat() depending on which one doesn't work. Given the inputs, one of these functions must work.

Comment: "depending on which one doesn't work" -- the failure you're looking to workaround is among different releases/versions of `h5py` or `scipy`, one of them may not have this feature available?

Comment: @BrianCain Yes. I think this is a rather general problem and I would be surprised if there wasn't a general solution.

Comment: What exactly means "doesn't work"? Function exists but it's execution raises and Exception? Function does not exists? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like that:

```
flag = True;
try:
    f = h5py.File(filepath)
except:
    flag = False;

try:
    if not flag:
        f = scipy.io.loadmat(filepath)
except:
    print('Error')
```

The problems in your code are:

- you are catching for the wrong error. Without specifying the error type you can handle all kinds of error in a single way (you can also add multiple `except` clauses)
- you are executing a potentially failing function inside the except clause. In this way you won't be able to handle new errors. I then splitted them in two separate try/except blocks.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: This may be what you want but catching _all errors_ with an empty (aka bare) `except:` is a very bad idea. Better to use multiple errors to catch like `except OSError, ImportError as e`; or separate `except` blocks with the appropriate type of error being handled. At the very least, if catching all errors with an bare except you should check for the error type to make sure there's not something else unexpected happening which you're code is ignoring. And once you've put that much logic in the bare except block, you'll probably figure see that it would've been easier to catch specific errors.

Answer (score 0):

First: your code should know whether a function is defined! That's not something external, it is something that is entirely in your power.

If an import might fail, maybe do something like

```
try:
    import h5py
    HAVE_H5PY = True
except ImportError:
    HAVE_H5PY = False
```

and then use that to check.

Second, you *could* instead do something like

```
if 'h5py' in globals():
```

but that is ugly and unnecessary (you have to catch the ImportError anyway, if that is the problem you're trying to solve).

Third, your error message has nothing to do with any of this, it is returned by one of those two commands. It is trying to create a file that already exists.

Comment: I don't have any problem importing h5py. My problem is with trying a different function automatically in case a function which is what I'm experiencing.

Comment: Well, you are catching NameError -- which would only be raised if `h5py` or `filepath` weren't defined as variables. But I still feel that your actual error message has nothing to do with your question, it's trying to create a file that exists. You'd probably get the same error if you only had `h5py.File(filepath)` and nothing else.

Comment: That's correct. In each case, filepath is a valid address but h5py.File() may not be the appropriate function...I would like to know how I can switch between functions automatically.

Comment: It depends on whether you know what will go wrong with either call if it does. For instance, if OSError is always the error you get if h5py doesn't work, then you should put that in the except: instead of NameError (as Kevin said already). You could also have a bare except:, but that's dangerous as it hides all errors, including those that are actual problems.

Answer (score 0):

> `error message = 'file exists'`

Your program is getting `EEXIST` and if you see a difference between trials with `h5py` and `scipy.io`, it's because they have different flags that they're passing to `open()` and perhaps differing states if you cleanup the files created between trials.

From the [`h5py.File` docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/file.html#opening-creating-files):

> Valid modes are:
>   ...
>
> ```
> r         Readonly, file must exist
> w         Create file, truncate if exists
> w- or x   Create file, fail if exists
> a         Read/write if exists, create otherwise (default)
> ```

Since you're looking to read the file (only?) you should specify 'r' as the mode.

If you're experiencing this problem only rarely, then perhaps it's a race generated by a [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use)-style error in `h5py`.

---

Indeed, such a TOCTOU design error exists in `h5py`.

https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/c699e741de64fda8ac49081e9ee1be43f8eae822/h5py/_hl/files.py#L99

```
# Open in append mode (read/write).
# If that fails, create a new file only if it won't clobber an
# existing one (ACC_EXCL)
try:
    fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl)
except IOError:
    fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_EXCL, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
```

This is the reason for the `O_EXCL` flag used by posix-style OSs.  `h5f.ACC_EXCL` likely does the same thing, but if it's only used upon failure of `h5f.ACC_RDWR` then its atomicity is diminished.